# How to get the port number from a log (splunk) by regular expressions?

Tags: regex, splunk

How to get the port number from a log (Splunk) by regular expressions:

```
{"info":{"seqno":0,"evtType":1,"oTime":null,"links":null,"id":"9b0ae9a9-e424-11e9-a309-fd988b74a8c5","origin":null,"relations":[],"details":"","severity":5,"time":1569918148265,"headId":"9b0ae9a9-e424-11e9-a309-fd988b74a8c5","sa":2},"desc":{"alertId":{"desc":"The network port is down","label":"Link down"},"pointId":[{"desc":"Type: openflow\nIP: a.b.c.d","label":"device_name [a.b.c.d]"},{"desc":"","label":""},{"desc":"Network Interfaces","label":""},{"desc":"","label":"**eth-0-36**"}]},"id":{"alertId":"16","component":1,"pointId":["a-b-c-d","dev","1","36"]}}
```

Port notation can be different depends on the device:

Eth1/1.2; Eth1/2.500; eth-0-19/4; eth-0-4; Eth1/4

I have tried `\W+((?i)Eth....(?-i))\W+` but it doesn't work in Splunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match the different formats, you might use:

```
\beth\d*(?:-\d+)*(?:/\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?\b
```

In parts

- `\b` Word boundary
- `eth\d*` Match eth an 0+ digits
- `(?:-\d+)*` Repeat 0+ times - and 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `/\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match `/`, 1+ digits and optionally a `.` and 1+ digits
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OvtbTO/1)

Use a case insensitive match or use `[Ee]th`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
(?<=")[Ee]th.*?(?=")
```

It just looks for the eth string between 2 quotes.  But if you want it to be more strict to the test cases you offered, @TheFourthBird s answer might be better